# How can I generate static REST api documentation from swagger 1.2 annotated spring MVC application

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger

I have spring MVC based REST controllers annotated with Swagger 1.2 annotations for all my REST apis.

I have my swagger documentation working just fine with these annotations.

I'd like to generate static html pages with the above documentation so that they can be hosted independent of my web app.

Is there a way to generate this ?

Comment: https://github.com/nknapp/swagger-to-html hope this one help you.

Comment: I do not have a swagger.json file. My controller code is annotated with swagger 1.2 annotations. swagger-to-html seems to need a swagger.json file to start with.